# Checkbox invisible in IE8 however visible in Firefox

Tags: css, checkbox, internet-explorer-8

I am having a very weird bug in Internet Explorer 8 for [this website](http://goo.gl/TDiXD). In IE8, the checkbox disappears. However it is there for other browsers such as Firefox or Chrome. In Chrome or Firefox, one can see the checkbox beside the text "Click to compare". However in Internet Explorer it is invisible.

Any idea why that is happening? I need it to be visible so that user can click on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remove `float:left` from `compare_check regular-checkbox` it starts to show in IE8.

Use conditional comments or `float:none\9` to hack it for IE8 only.